# RRuleStrOptions.dtstart does not work when there is a exdate

Tags: javascript, rrule

I am using `rrulestr` from the [rrule.js](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/rrule) library to parse a set of rrule strings.

I want to set the `dtstart` using the RRuleStrOptions and tried the following.

```
const rrule = rrulestr(
   "RRULE:INTERVAL=1;FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=5",
   { dtstart: new Date("2021-08-01T10:00:00+00:00") }
);
```

This worked perfectly. (Below is the output of `rrule.toString()`)

```
DTSTART:20210801T100000Z
RRULE:INTERVAL=1;FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=5
```

But when I added exdate to the rrule string, the `dtstart` option was not applied.

```
const rrule = rrulestr(
  "RRULE:INTERVAL=1;FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=5\\nEXDATE:20210802T100000Z",
  { dtstart: new Date("2021-08-01T10:00:00+00:00") }
)
```

Below is the output of `rrule.toString()`

```
RRULE:INTERVAL=1;FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=5
EXDATE:20210802T100000Z
```

Please help me fix this issue.
Thank you for your generous support.